# How can I fill each petal separately using begin_fill()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I have the following code that generates a petal pattern for a flower I'm trying to build. However, the problem is the fill part.

What should happen is each petal to be filled individually:

[image]

Instead, what happens is this:

[image]

```
import turtle
import math

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("white")

def draw_leaf(turtle, side, theta = 0):
    angle = 2
    turtle.color("#67bd3c")
    for x in range(-180,180):
        y = math.sin(math.radians(angle))
        angle += 1
        y = y * side
        x_axis = (x % 180) * math.cos(math.radians(theta)) + y * math.sin(math.radians(theta))
        y_axis = (x % 180) * (-1 * (math.sin(math.radians(theta)))) + y * math.cos(math.radians(theta))
        turtle.goto(-1 * x_axis, -1 * y_axis)
    return

def draw_flower(turtle, petals):
    for x in range(petals):
        theta = 180/(petals - 1)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.begin_fill()
        draw_leaf(turtle, 35, theta * x)
        turtle.end_fill()
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.left(theta)
    return

draw_flower(turtle,4)

wn.exitonclick()
```

Comment: This isn't related to your problem, but you don't have to have a `return` statement at the end of your functions. If you remove those lines, your code will behave the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like each `draw_leaf` call begins when the turtle is at the far end of the leaf that it just previously drew. So the polygon that is filled during the current `draw_leaf` includes that end point. This is more apparent if you draw each leaf with a different color.

One possible solution is to `goto` the center of the flower after your `penup`, before you draw the next leaf.

```
def draw_flower(turtle, petals):
    start = turtle.pos()
    for x in range(petals):
        theta = 180/(petals - 1)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.begin_fill()
        draw_leaf(turtle, 35, theta * x)
        turtle.end_fill()
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(*start)
        turtle.left(theta)
    return
```